# Automatically import modules from a namespace package

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

Is there a way to automatically import modules from an implicit namespace package ([PEP420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)), if we are not allowed to have *__init__.py* files?

I decided to split my package `mylib` into two namespace packages: `mylib-core` and `mylib-extra`.

Before, when I would run `import mylib`, I would automatically import `mylib.module`, `mylib.module2`, etc., using code in my *__init__.py* file:

```
# __init__.py

__all__ = [
    'module1',
    'module2',
]

from . import *
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same behaviour in a namespace package? I have a lot of existing code that expects this behaviour.